# Customization of the Balkan FamilyTree Js library

Tags: javascript, family-tree

Can you tell me if there is any possibility of adding custom buttons or links, or changing existing buttons and their routes on the display of the library family tree? For example, add a button next to a person's circle.[image]

Example of filling in the code for tree rendering

```
var family = new FamilyTree(document.getElementById("tree"), {
        template: 'john',
        
        nodeMouseClick: FamilyTree.action.details,
        siblingSeparation: 150,
        enableSearch: false,
        nodeBinding: {
            img_0: "img",
            field_0: 'name',
            field_1: "date",
        },

        editForm: {
            titleBinding: false,
            photoBinding: "img",
            edit: false,
            generateElementsFromFields: false,
            addMore: false,
            cancelBtn: 'Закрыть',

            saveAndCloseBtn: 'Редактировать',
            elements: [
                {type: 'textbox', label: 'Полное имя', id: 'name', binding: 'fullname'},
                [
                    {type: 'textbox', label: 'Дата рождения', binding: 'birthDate'},
                    {type: 'textbox', label: 'Дата смерти', binding: 'deathDate'}
                ],
                [
                    {type: 'textbox', label: 'Место рождения', binding: 'placebirth'},
                    {type: 'textbox', label: 'Место смерти', binding: 'burialplace'},
                ],
                {type: 'textbox', label: 'Причина смерти', binding: 'reasondeath'},
                // {type: 'textbox', label: 'Photo Url', }


            ],
            buttons: {
                edit: {
                    icon: FamilyTree.icon.edit(24, 24, '#fff'),
                    text: 'Edit',
                    hideIfEditMode: true,
                    hideIfDetailsMode: false
                },
                remove: null,
                share: null,
                pdf: null
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of BALKAN FamilyTreeJS

Created a [Code demo](https://code.balkan.app/family-tree-js/add-html-button#JS) for you with a button and on click event listener

[image]

Comment: Does this not work for the addNode() method ?